# How can I get a MD5 of an entire database and use it to poll for changes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do some sort of polling to listen to updates occuring on a database. So far I was considering getting a MD5 hash (or any type or hash) of the database (or couple tables), store that in a variable, and run a thread that loops this procedure over and over, comparing it with the last result. If theres a different, a button is set to Enabled which trigers the database load function.

Is that a good way to do it? If not, why? If yes, how?

The part I'm I don't really know how to acheive is to get the MD5 hash on the side of the database. I could easly get all the data then get a md5 hash of it, all client side, but... yea.

I'm using LINQ to SQL but I'm afraid I will only be able to use the context to run a Raw query. This is on WinForms, .NET 3.5 (not that it should matter however...).

Any hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the "database load function" - does it cache data from those two tables?

Comment: DataContext => BindingSource. Not sure what would be considered cached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use the right tool for the job:

> > - [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx) Change tracking in SQL Server 2008 enables applications to obtain only changes that have been made to the user tables, along with the information about those changes
> > - [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105)) Change data capture is designed to capture insert, update, and delete activity applied to SQL Server tables, and to make the details of the changes available in an easily consumed relational format. The change tables used by change data capture contain columns that mirror the column structure of a tracked source table, along with the metadata needed to understand the changes that have occurred.

Note that both technologies mentioned above are targeting occasionally connected system (eg. mobile users connecting on the rod to refresh their local snapshot). For a system that is permanently connected and needs to refresh its display when a change occurs on the back end the right technology is [Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/).

Comment: Thanks, should be what I'm looking for. I'll try it and get back to you in a moment. However, I'm pretty sure we're running on SQL 2005. :( So I'll check the second option.

Comment: Yes, both technologies are SQL Server 2008 and later. Query Notification is 2005.

Comment: Havent managed to make Query Notification work so far... Do you have any recommanded tutorials?

Comment: I'll just accept this answer and open a new question cause even that exemple is acting up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Detecting modifications to a database by polling **all the data** is just about the worst possible idea. If you do not have control over the clients that do the actual modification then AFAIK there is no sane way to do this (everyone should be cooperating if your app needs this level of information).

As a workaround that still does sound horrible, you could add a [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) column to all of your tables and for each table poll by selecting the maximum value and comparing it to a locally cached "old maximum". Whenever a row is updated its `rowversion` will change, so not only will you know that something has been updated but you will also be able to select just the updated records from the table if needed.

Comment: If you read the question properly, I said I want to avoid polling all the data, hence why I'm asking how to get a MD5 hash on the SQL side, not on the client side.

Comment: The problem with rowversion is tracking deletes.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: Sure. I 'm an SQL server newbie, so that was the best I could come up with. Upvoted the correct answer of course.